# Table won't show in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

For some reason my tables won't show up in IE7.
An example table looks like this:

```
<table class="stringingTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="selected">.</td>
<td>,</td>
<td>and</td>
<td>also</td>
<td>but</td>
<td>however</td>
<td>whereas</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The relevant css looks like this:

```
stringingTable {
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #9A2F00;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.stringingTable td.selected {
    display: table-cell;
}

.stringingTable td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 70px;
    display: none;
}
```

The table shows up fine in all modern browsers but this is a website for teachers in NI (who all use IE7 as they use [C2k](http://www.c2kni.net/c2k_services.html))

Comment: One does not simply design a webpage for IE7.

Comment: I mean design a webpage to be compatible with IE7.


zoom: 1 does nothing

Comment: Can you post your full html? i have a hunch that it is a DOCTYPE related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer versions less than 8 do not support the CSS table display properties, which include `table`, `inline-table`, and all properties of `table-*`. Unfortunately by setting those cells as `display: none`, you will not be able to redisplay them without altering the table's appearance (as you can't set them *back* to table cells).

I don't know if it will be helpful in your specific case, but you can try playing with `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` instead.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help. I decided to use a javascript function to vertically center inline elements in a div instead of using table cells

Answer (score 0):

You are using `display: none;` for all `TD`s, so you hide everything. It doesn't show up in Chrome either for me if I don't remove the `display: none`.

Comment: the top td has the class .selected which is set to display: table-cell;